# A kind of curve

Tags: exponential-function, curves

What function can this kind of curve correspond to ?
Some kind of exponential ? Thanks.
[See my Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZEn4.jpg)

Comment: There are many things that can produce that, the question is where did you get the graph? Is it the output of some dynamical system?

Comment: Does it eventually go to $0$ or non-$0$ limit? Does it have vertical tangent at the origin?

Comment: Hi. I have a series of 6 points, and with my graphical calculator (desmos.com), I found empirically a curve which approaches this : $ y = -ae^{xb} + c $ (a,b,c are reals). But I can't get the "little bell" at the top ... :-( @Conifold : No tangent at the origin and non-0 limit.

Comment: I am guessing "no tangent" means "vertical tangent".  $y=Ax^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x}$ with $0<\alpha<1$ would produce that and the bell, but the limit will be $0$. To get non-$0$ limit you can add $B(1-e^{-\gamma x})$ to it.

Comment: Yesss...!! It works like a charm ! I use $ f(x)= ax^αe^{-βx}+b(1-e^{-γx}) $ 
and that's exactly what I wanted. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ f(x)=ax^αe^{-βx}+b(1-e^{−γx}) $
- Solved / See comments above.